# Backgroundworker - сохранение данных в файл

Tags: c#

Задача моего курсового проекта заключается в работе с Ексель файлами. При сохранении возникает проблемка - долго сохраняется, из-за чего создал фоновый поток сохранения. Но теперь появилась другая проблема - "пользователь" может попытатся открыть другой файл во время сохранения что приведёт к серьёзным последствиям для информации. Как я могу избежать этого?

Оставлять "зависание" программы не хочу. Пытался сделать форму-диалог сохранения с анимацией, но так и не удалось.

Если надо какой-то ещё код, чтобы понять проблему - скину сюда. Не хочу захламлять вопрос.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    saveFile(dataGridView1, toolStripStatusLabel1, filePath);           
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Файл " + filePath + " збережено!");
}
```

Comment: тю, заведите флаг, который будет означать, что файл сохраняется и открывать новый нельзя

Comment: Вот, чесно говорю, минуту назад об этом думал))